# Change the list of classes a class inherits from

Tags: python, class, subclass

I am completely aware that this is **NOT** something you usually want to do.

I am using a library featuring (unfortunately) a lot of type-checking. I have a working solution, however, only when one of those type-checks in the library is commented out. I would like to have a solution which does not require modification of the library code.

To be more specific, I need to bypass this piece of code:

```
def is_valid(arg):
    return inspect.isclass(arg) and issubclass(arg, SomeClass)
```

It is not possible that my `arg` is a subclass of `SomeClass` due to some stuff happening in `SomeClass`'s metaclass which is unwanted to happen for my case.

So the only option is to hack. Can I somehow make Python think that `arg` inherits from `SomeClass` while it actually does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could do this...

```
import inspect

def is_valid(arg):
    return inspect.isclass(arg) and issubclass(arg, Base)

class OtherType(type):
    pass

class Base(metaclass=OtherType):
    pass

class SurpriseBase:
    pass

class SurpriseDerived(SurpriseBase):
    pass

print(f'SurpriseDerived is_valid: {is_valid(SurpriseDerived)}')

SurpriseDerived.__bases__ = (Base,)

print(f'Base metaclass: {type(Base)}')
print(f'SurpriseDerived metaclass: {type(SurpriseDerived)}')
print(f'SurpriseDerived is_valid: {is_valid(SurpriseDerived)}')
```

Output:

```
SurpriseDerived is_valid: False
Base metaclass: <class '__main__.OtherType'>
SurpriseDerived metaclass: <class 'type'>
SurpriseDerived is_valid: True
```

Comment: Is is really THAT simple? I almost feel ashamed that I have not tried this before asking. Thanks!

Comment: Fair warning: this solution answers the question as it was asked, but there could be side effects of doing this (I have never had a reason to do this). If there are, please share them!

Comment: Thanks for the warning, if I ever run into an issue, I will let everyone know here. But so far, everything seems to be working as expected for me.